Task Scheduler jobs not visible
We have tasks in Task scheduler running under account XYZ on a Windows PC. The XYZ user account has been disabled, and users have to logon using their own domain account.
When the user logs on, they don't see the tasks, and also the task doesn't run, and the files don't get updated.
I tried the import option but couldn't succeed due to permission issue. I also set it to SYSTEM as user account under security options
What other option do I have to make sure the other user can see the jobs and also it should run automatically at the set time?

Users must be administrators to view or edit tasks that are not owned by them.
The correct resolution is to Export the task, delete the current task, then import it as the required user account.
Note that this was a significant behavior change introduced in Windows 10 from previous versions, due to it was a known attack vector.
It's also possible to code this, but that is approaching beyond the scope of the forum and the capability may be defeated in a future update.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/what-s-new-in-task-scheduler
"For security reasons, a non-administrator user cannot view nor manage a Windows Task Scheduler task that was created by another user".
https://www.osdeploy.com/blog/2021/scheduled-tasks/task-permissions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-change

I can understand that non admin user cannot view or make changes to the jobs but atleast the jobs should run on the given time and update the job but this isn't too happening...
